# Python | Logging | separating core and logging

Tags: python-3.x, logging

**Goal:**

Would like to keep logging initialisation separated from core projects. And any change in logging frameworks should not require code changes in the applications.

To achieve it, I created a common-logging module and using it in the core projects.

**Sample to demonstrate:**

AppLogging is a singleton class. As per my current knowledge, it's not needed to be singleton that all logger objects are attached to the single rootLogger as children.

```
class AppLogging:

def __new__(cls, name):
    if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
        cls.instance = super(AppLogging, cls).__new__(cls)
        cls.logger = logging.getLogger(name) 
    return cls.instance

def __init__(self, name): # passing the names from the caller to get it properly printed
    pass

def info(self, message, key=None):
    if key:
        self.logger.info(f'{key}:{message}')
    else:
        self.logger.info(f'{message}')
```

**Log_Config**

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  file:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: simple
    encoding: utf8
loggers:
  simpleExample:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: no
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]
```

**Testing:**

```
log_util.initialize_logging("./test_log_conf.yaml", "./splunk.log")
logger = AppLogging.AppLogging(os.path.basename((__file__)))

logger.info("Hi")
```

**Problems:**

If I change the formatter to print the line number as well, it prints the line number of the logger line from AppLogging instead of the original caller. I understand that it's expected. How should we handle it to achieve the goal?

Edit:

stack level attribute solves the above problem? Thanks to SO.

Now, the following question only remains.

And Is it the correct/standard approach of doing it? Kindly suggest.